# Directive on span inside button element not working in firefox

Tags: java, angularjs, firefox

I have a tooltip custom directive on span element and this span element is placed inside button element. On hover i want to show that tooltip

Comment: Can you show some of your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

do something like this in `css`

```
button>span{
    display:none;
}
button:hover button>span{
    display:block;
}
```